# function share in header and sidebar component angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I need to sidebar component function in sidebar.

my header component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SidebarComponent } from '../sidebar/sidebar.component';

@ViewChild(SidebarComponent) SidebarComponent;


ngOnInit() {
  this.SidebarComponent.testFunction();
}
```

sidebar component

```
testFunction() {
   console.log('value');
}
```

I added an essential code block for the understanding purpose. when I use the above code error said,

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'testFunction' of undefined
>           at HeaderComponent.push../src/app/layout/components/header/header.component.ts.HeaderComponent.ngOnInit (header.component.ts:57)

can u help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

call it after child view is initialized.

```
  @ViewChild(SidebarComponent) sidebarComponent: SidebarComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.sidebarComponent.testFunction(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For sharing of functions in Angular, it is better to use a service and call it's functions in both of the components.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SharedService {

  constructor() { }

  sharedFunction(){
    console.log('here');
  }

}
```

And in both of components, component1:

```
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '.....',
  templateUrl: '.......',
  styleUrls: ['........']
})
export class Component1  implements OnInit{

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.sharedService.sharedFunction();
  }

}
```

component2:

```
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '.....',
  templateUrl: '.......',
  styleUrls: ['........']
})

export class Component2  implements OnInit{

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.sharedService.sharedFunction();
  }

}
```

Comment: can not we share function without using service ??

Answer (score 0):

Could be done using a service. For illustration purpose let's call it HeaderAndSidebarService:

Filename: header-and-sidebar.service.ts

```
@import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class HeaderAndSideBarService {
    public testFunction() {
       console.log('value');
    }
}
```

To use the service, provide it within both header and sidebar component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderAndSideBarService } from "./header-and-sidebar.service";

@Component({
    ...,
    providers: [HeaderAndSideBarService]
})
export class HeaderComponent {
    constructor(private service: HeaderAndSideBarService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.service.testFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: can not we share function without using service ??

Comment: @gihankumara There is another possible way, define function as a utility function which is not a member of  a class: export function testFunction() { ... }